# I have multiple YouTube links I'm trying to bunch them into a single playlist. Is It Possible?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I'm trying to save time rather than adding each video one by one to a playlist. YouTube doesn't have a feature to dump multiple URLs to convert to a playlist. Is there any script, or program I could use to achieve this task?. I tried using a script beforehand, but turns out it's limited to 50 videos on an unlisted playlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple spreadsheet playlist generator: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=1950325992)**

Just add YouTube links in any desired order and press that red text in cell **B1** to play it.

[image]